# LiPo to 5v TPS61200 vs TPS61090

Tags: power, lipo, switching-regulator

I am working on a hobby project that I want to power with a LiPo Cell battery which provides 3.7v with a max of 2A output. I need to power a 5v peripheral that has varying current draw up to the 1A-1.2A range. In this case it seems I could use a [TPS61200](http://www.ti.com/product/tps61200) switching regulator or a [TPS61090](http://www.ti.com/product/tps61090). I am leaning toward the latter because I could really use 96% efficiency (vs 90% on the TPS61200) and the low battery indication, but I was wondering if there was any reason to use the TPS61200 in this case?

Answer (score 1):

No, the TPS61090 will allow you to get more efficiency and higher output current. You don't need the TPS61200's ability to run at very low input voltages. The TPS61200 is in a smaller 3mm x 3mm package vs. 4mm x 4mm for the TPS61090, but you didn't mention space being an issue.

Comment: Space isn't an issue in this case.